# Java Home wasn't set properly?

Tags: java, linux, matlab, installation

I am trying to install MATLAB on my Fedora 22. At the end, I get an error

> The application encountered an unexpected error and needs to close. You may want to try re-installing your product(s). More information can be found at /tmp/mathworks_root.log

When I look in mathworks_root.log file, I see that Java Home is not set properly during installation step

> Java Home /tmp/mathworks_32206/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre

although I set  this environment variable, output of this command

> echo $JAVA_HOME
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.45-40.b14.fc22.x86_64/jre/bin/java

Do you know, why this happens?

Thanks!

Comment: JAVA_HOME should be only till '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.45-40.b14.fc22.x86_64'

Comment: Set your JAVA_HOME correctly...its not correct

Comment: I did it, and same thing happens.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that your installation script doesn't know which java to use. Maybe it doesn't recognise the `$JAVA_HOME` variable? Try running the command `java -version`, it should output you the java version if the command is recognised. Depending on what the command returns I'd try the following:

1. If you get a correct response from `java -version` run the installation script again in a new shell session. Try looking at the script itself, maybe it requires some specific version of java?
2. If you don't get a correct response, make sure your java is installed in some directory, and instead of specifying the `$JAVA_HOME` simply add an alias to this command in some system folder. My setup is this:

   - various JDKs in `/opt/` folder:

   `/opt> ls -l
   drwxr-xr-x  8 kmejka kmejka 4096 kwi 10 20:53 jdk1.7.0_79/
   drwxr-xr-x  8 kmejka kmejka 4096 gru 18  2014 jdk1.8.0_31/`

   - symlink `/opt` to the jdk I want to use globally:

   `kmejka@kmejka-work /opt> ll jdk
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 cze 26 14:20 jdk -> /opt/jdk1.8.0_31//`

   - symlinks in `/usr/bin` to all the needed java commands (you need at least the command ```java``, I've got more of them:

   `kmejka@kmejka-work /opt> ll /usr/bin/java*
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 lut  1 12:05 /usr/bin/java -> /opt/jdk/bin/java*
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 lut  1 12:05 /usr/bin/javac -> /opt/jdk/bin/javac*
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 lut  1 12:06 /usr/bin/javah -> /opt/jdk/bin/javah*
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 lut  1 12:05 /usr/bin/javap -> /opt/jdk/bin/javap*`

This setup gives me flexibility to easily change the java version that I need - just switch the symlink!

Comment: There is no any requirements for java version in scripting file.

Comment: And the error which I get at the end is "java.lang.NullPointerException installation"

Comment: @user3616359 I get that. My point of running ```java -version``` was that this easily answers these questions - do you have java installed? is it properly installed? what version is it?

Comment: I have managed to install other version of MATLAB. Probably, the problem was with installation files. Java version is 1.7.0_79.